# Initializing multiple dependent services in Javascript

Tags: javascript, initialization

I have a large project that comprises of multiple, dependent services. The services start asynchronously, some take a while to finish startup. Currently, I start each process and tie them all together manually (every service receives its dependencies via arguments).

I'm looking for a better way of doing that.
What I would ideally want, is a way to declaratively specify the list of services, giving each its dependency list and have some "supervisor" sorting out the correct initialization order and starting up each service as soon as its dependencies are up.

I know the concept of DI, but I dislike it, because I prefer explicit dependency specification.

Comment: Have you tried AMD modules?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), in your case `Promise.all(iterable)` could be useful in your case.

Basically `Promise.all` can be useful for aggregating the results of multiple asynchronous requests.

Comment: This is only a solution for starting everything in parallel, it will not resolve the dependencies and figure out the correct order.

Comment: You can use a more "pyramid" approach still using promises.

Comment: @avishorp Not sure what you mean by "resolve" when you actually want to explicitly specify dependencies? The correct order will be automatically achieved by using `then`.

Comment: Taking this approach, I will have to make sure that when I call the initializer of a specific service, all the promises of the services on which it depends are already in place. That means that I have to go through the list of service and resolve the order in which they should be initialized. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @avishorp I do not think really. But maybe I do not understand your questions fully...